# Learning rate decay in TensorFlow - Error with piecewise_constant function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to work with a code base for Tiny YOLO v2. I am running into the following error while declaring a learning rate schedule. I can see that my `step` values are the same size as my `lr` but am unsure what a good fix is. I have included my attempt at explicitly declaring the values (with `steps` smaller than `lr`) and the error that results in as well.

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "scripts/train_tiny_yolo.py", line 335, in 
>       lr = tf.train.piecewise_constant(global_step, steps, lrs)
>     File "/Users/nivedithakalavakonda/Desktop/python_environments/objectdet_tf1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/learning_rate_decay.py", line 147, in piecewise_constant
>       name=name)
>     File "/Users/nivedithakalavakonda/Desktop/python_environments/objectdet_tf1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/learning_rate_decay_v2.py", line 166, in piecewise_constant
>       "The length of boundaries should be 1 less than the length of values")
>   ValueError: The length of boundaries should be 1 less than the length of values

Here is the relevant section from my code:

```
    base_lr = params.get('learning_rate', 1e-3)
    steps = params.get('steps', [3000, 4000, 5000])

    steps_and_lrs = []
    if steps[0] > 100:
        # Warm-up
        steps_and_lrs += [
            (25, base_lr / 100),
            (50, base_lr / 10)
        ]

    steps_and_lrs += [(step, base_lr * 10**(-i)) for i, step in enumerate(steps)]
    steps, lrs = zip(*steps_and_lrs)

    # Alternative attempt to explicitly declare lr and steps values
    # steps =( 50, 20000, 30000, 40000)
    # lrs = (1e-05, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.0001, 1e-05)

    max_iter = steps[-1]
    lr = tf.train.piecewise_constant(global_step, steps, lrs)
    np.set_printoptions(precision=3, suppress=True)

    opt = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(lr, momentum=0.9)
    grads_and_vars = opt.compute_gradients(loss)
    clip_value = params.get('clip_gradients')

    if clip_value is not None:
        grads_and_vars = [(tf.clip_by_value(g, -clip_value, clip_value), v) for g, v in grads_and_vars]

    train_op = opt.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars,
            global_step=global_step)

    merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
```

**What have I tried:**

When I give the values for steps and lr explicitly, I get the following value error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "scripts/train_tiny_yolo.py", line 363, in 
>       grads_and_vars = [(tf.clip_by_value(g, -clip_value, clip_value), v) for g, v in grads_and_vars]   File "scripts/train_tiny_yolo.py",
>   line 363, in 
>       grads_and_vars = [(tf.clip_by_value(g, -clip_value, clip_value), v) for g, v in grads_and_vars]   File
>   "/Users/nivedithakalavakonda/Desktop/python_environments/objectdet_tf1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py",
>   line 180, in wrapper
>       return target(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/nivedithakalavakonda/Desktop/python_environments/objectdet_tf1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/clip_ops.py",
>   line 69, in clip_by_value
>       t = ops.convert_to_tensor(t, name="t")   File "/Users/nivedithakalavakonda/Desktop/python_environments/objectdet_tf1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 1039, in convert_to_tensor
>       return convert_to_tensor_v2(value, dtype, preferred_dtype, name)   File
>   "/Users/nivedithakalavakonda/Desktop/python_environments/objectdet_tf1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 1097, in convert_to_tensor_v2
>       as_ref=False)   File "/Users/nivedithakalavakonda/Desktop/python_environments/objectdet_tf1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 1175, in internal_convert_to_tensor
>       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)   File
>   "/Users/nivedithakalavakonda/Desktop/python_environments/objectdet_tf1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py",
>   line 304, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
>       return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)   File "/Users/nivedithakalavakonda/Desktop/python_environments/objectdet_tf1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py",
>   line 245, in constant
>       allow_broadcast=True)   File "/Users/nivedithakalavakonda/Desktop/python_environments/objectdet_tf1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py",
>   line 283, in _constant_impl
>       allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))   File "/Users/nivedithakalavakonda/Desktop/python_environments/objectdet_tf1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py",
>   line 454, in make_tensor_proto
>       raise ValueError("None values not supported.")

Currently using TensorFlow 1.13.1.

Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if sharing the large code base will be more insightful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the error when I ensure the `steps` and `lrs` are not the same size arises from the `grad` values having `None` in it. I solved it by using the following workaround:

```
    if grad is None:
        return grad
    return _tf.clip_by_value(grad, -clip_value, clip_value)

    if clip_value is not None:
            grads_and_vars = opt.compute_gradients(loss)
            clipped_gradients = [(ClipIfNotNone(g, clip_value), v) for g, v in grads_and_vars]
            train_op = opt.apply_gradients(clipped_gradients, global_step=global_step)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, `steps`and `lrs` are of the same size. Please check the example provided [[here]](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/piecewise_constant_decay). According to this documentation, the number of values in `steps` should be 1 less than the number of values in `lrs`. Also, please note, there is a bug in this scheduler. You can check it [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/29903).

If you are using tensorflow 2.0, below is an example that works. I have not tested this with tf 1.13.

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2 import learning_rate_schedule
n_step_epoch = 100
init_lr = 0.01
decay = 0.1

decay_type = 'multistep_15_25_100'
milestones = decay_type.split('_')
milestones.pop(0)
milestones = list(map(lambda x: int(x), milestones))
boundaries = np.multiply(milestones,n_step_epoch)
values = [init_lr] + [init_lr/(decay**-i) for i in  range(1,len(milestones)+1)]
learning_rate =learning_rate_schedule.PiecewiseConstantDecay(boundaries.tolist(), values)
```

Hope this helps!